# Trying to achieve the jquery "blind" effect thorugh hover or mouseover and -out, but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, html

My inspiration came from this link:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-blind.htm

I was trying to achieve almost the effect, just through mouseover and -out and sliding it vertically, but no success yet...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".player").mouseover(function() {
    $(".player").hide("blind", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
  });
  $(".player").mouseout(function() {
    $(".player").show("blind", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
  });
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player">
  ssdssdffsf
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing the jQuery UI extension

Add this script to your document and the effect should work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This is the script used in the tutorial provided. There may also be more updated versions of jQuery UI available as of now.

Comment: you're right, nevertheless the code still has some defects. As soon as i hover over it, the div hides, reaperes instantly again, without me mousing out. It keeps repeating that a few times after the hover, without me even "mousing on" it...quite odd... don't get confused by my use of "hover" and "mouse..", but i hope you can follow me anyway

Comment: the div reappears because when you use `.hide();` the div is set to `display:none;` and thus the `MouseOut` event handler is automatically triggered(your mouse is no longer on the div) I would advise you use a wrapper div with a default size to trigger the functions or use `visibility:hidden;` instead of hide(); so the div is still part of the document.